# Execution Plan for a long stored proc cuts off. How to view it in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2008

I am trying to look at an execution plan for a sproc that has a massive amount of statements, looping, etc...  As you can imagine, the execution plan is really long.  In fact, SSMS gets confused before the interesting part that I am trying to look at.

[image]

Is there anyway to see the entire execution plan?

Btw, using SSMS 2008 to hit SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What do you mean, cuts off?  There are vertical and horizontal scrollbars.  You can also always just view the xml

Comment: @BrianWhite Note the missing edges in connectors - they don't connect to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the free [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp). We've made many enhancements to the graphical view and, while you can't always perfect the layout for an obnoxiously large plan, there are several other tabs where you can glean valuable information without having to find it on the graphical display and without having to parse XML.

(Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.)

Comment: Oh, wow.  That's an excellent tool.  You should charge for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, look at the free SSMS Tools, it has the ability to take a snapshot of the entire plan.

www.ssmstoolspack.com